# Consulta por búsqueda de datos

Tags: android-studio

les comento que sigo con el proyecto de android, pretendo que cuando el usuario ingrese un repuesto para la patente que corresponda si por ejemplo para la AA4040 ya esta ingresada el óptico derecho, pero viene otro usuario y quiere ingresar el óptico derecho y debe enviar un mansaje, por lo cual realice el siguiente arreglo en php de esta manera:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$Repuesto = $_GET['Repuestos'];
$Patente = $_GET['Patente_Vehiculo'];
$consulta = "SELECT Patente_Vehiculo, Repuestos, Activo FROM presupuesto2 WHERE Repuestos = '$Repuesto' AND Patente_Vehiculo = '$Patente' 
AND (Activo = 1)";
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (mysqli_num_rows($datos) > 0) {
// Si se encontró el repuesto, enviar un mensaje JSON indicando que ya fue ingresado
echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Este repuesto ya fue ingresado para esta patente de vehículo"));
} else {
// Si el repuesto no existe, enviar un mensaje JSON indicando que puede ser ingresado
echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Este repuesto no ha sido ingresado para esta patente de vehículo"));
}
mysqli_close ($conexion);
?>
```

este funciona bien y lo probe en el postmann, después lo llevo al android de esta manera:

```
private void buscar3(){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.88/gestion/buscar_presupuesto17.php?Repuestos=" + txtrepuesto3.getText().toString() + "&Patente_Vehiculo =" + m.getText().toString();
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            5000, // tiempo de espera inicial
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, // número máximo de reintentos
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT // factor de aumento del tiempo de espera
    );
    //JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            //if (response.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    //jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
                    String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //txtrepuesto3.setText(jsonObject.getString("Repuestos"));
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Este repuesto ya fue ingresado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //txtrepuesto3.setText("");
                    //txtrepuesto3.requestFocus();
                    if (mensaje.equals("Este repuesto ya fue ingresado para esta patente de vehículo")) {
                        txtrepuesto3.setText("");
                        txtrepuesto3.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        // Llamar a ejecutarServicio si el repuesto no ha sido ingresado
                        ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.88/gestion/insertar_presupuesto2.php");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            //} else {
            //    ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.88/gestion/insertar_presupuesto2.php");
            //}
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de red. Por favor, verifica tu conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error del servidor. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de autenticación. Por favor, verifica tus credenciales", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de parseo. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No se pudo establecer conexión. Por favor, verifica tu conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tiempo de espera agotado. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error desconocido. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

al momento de ejecutarlo en el dispositivo siempre me manda el siguiente mensaje de error: Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de parseo. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();, trato de solucionarlo y cambiar desde jsonobject a jsonarray y siempre el mismo mensaje de error, soy novato en estas lides de android y quiero tratar de ver y entender el motivo del porque pasa esto, favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

como soy nuevo en estas lides he encontrado la solución a mi problema para los que a furo pasen por lo mismo, primero el arreglo json:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$Repuesto = $_GET['Repuestos'] ?? NULL;
$Patente = $_GET['Patente_Vehiculo'] ?? NULL;
$consulta = "SELECT Patente_Vehiculo, Repuestos, Activo FROM presupuesto2 
WHERE Repuestos = '$Repuesto' AND Patente_Vehiculo = '$Patente' 
AND (Activo = 1)";
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (mysqli_num_rows($datos) > 0) {
// Si se encontró el repuesto, enviar un mensaje JSON indicando que ya fue ingresado
echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Este repuesto ya fue ingresado para esta patente de vehículo"));
} else {
// Si el repuesto no existe, enviar un mensaje JSON indicando que puede ser ingresado
echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Este repuesto no ha sido ingresado para esta patente de vehículo"));
}
mysqli_close ($conexion);
?>
```

posteriormente al llevarlo al android queda de esta manera:

```
private void buscar7(){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.88/gestion/buscar_presupuesto17.php?Repuestos=" + txtrepuesto3.getText().toString() + "&Patente_Vehiculo=" + m.getText().toString();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");
                    if (mensaje.equals("Este repuesto ya fue ingresado para esta patente de vehículo")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Este repuesto ya fue ingresado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtrepuesto3.setText("");
                        txtvalor2.setText("");
                        txtrepuesto3.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.88/gestion/insertar_presupuesto2.php");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de red. Por favor, verifica tu conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error del servidor. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de autenticación. Por favor, verifica tus credenciales", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de parseo. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No se pudo establecer conexión. Por favor, verifica tu conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tiempo de espera agotado. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error desconocido. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

ojala que les sirva para los nuevos en android como yo, costo para sacarlo pero funciona muy bien